# MySQL ASP.net Connection string error

Tags: mysql, asp.net, connection-string

I'm trying to connect to MySQL from my asp.net website on a hosted platform. My connection string looks fine, all the login details and server IP are correct but I am still getting an error on the page:

```
[Win32Exception (0x80004005): The network path was not found]    
provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server
```

web.config connection string:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="Conn" connectionString="Server=xxxx;Database=xxxx;Uid=xxxx;Pwd=xxxx;" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Can you guys give me any more info why this might be the case? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your server is not running or if running, your code cannot access this - firewall, etc. Or you didn't granted privileges for the IP of your app.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like on this occasion there was a random Import that was making my site think it was using MSSQL rather than MySQL. Removed this and it's now working. Thanks for the help!